# Converting urls into lowercase?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

Is there any straightforward to convert all incoming urls to lowercase before they get matched against urlpatterns in `run_wsgi_app(webapp.WSGIApplication(urlpatterns))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to wrap the instance of `WSGIApplication` with your own WSGI app that lowercases the URL in the WSGI environment -- but then the environment would just stay modified, which may have other unpleasant effects. Why not just add `(?i)` to the regex patterns you use in `urlpatterns` instead?

Comment: Thanks.
But how will this work in '/(?P<some_category>\w+)/edit/(?P<item_id>\w+)/?' where 'edit' might be 'EDIT'?

Comment: @gmsd, as I said, just add `(?i)` to the pattern; for example, use `'(?i)/(?P<some_category>\w+)/edit/(?P<item_id>\w+)/?'` (just like your pattern plus `(?i)` in front, to tell `re` that the match is cases-insensitive. See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?#regular-expression-syntax .

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could modify your CGI environment variables before executing the WSGIApplication instance.

```
os.putenv(os.getenv('PATH_INFO').lower())
```

Something along those lines. I've done this myself for slight URL modifications, however I 301 redirected to the new URL; I didn't continue processing with WSGI.

Comment: This solution will work (with the caveats Alex mentioned), but WSGI middleware is a better idea.